# Dictionary-like matching on string in R

Tags: r, dplyr, strsplit, vocabulary

I have a dataframe in which a string variable is an informal list of elements, that can be split on a symbol. I would like to make operaion on these elements on the basis of another dataset.

e.g. task: Calculate the sum of the elements

```
df_1 <- data.frame(element=c(1:2),groups=c("A,B,C","A,D"))
df_2 <- data.frame(groups=c("A","B","C","D"), values=c(1:4))

desired <- data.frame(element=c(1:2),groups=c("A,B,C","A,D"),sum=c(6,5))
```

Comment: Now it's fixed, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be to split the 'groups' by the delimiter `,` to expand the rows with `separate_rows`, do a join with the key/val dataset ('df_2'), groued by 'element', get the `sum` of 'values'

```
library(tidyverse)
df_1 %>% 
  separate_rows(groups) %>% 
  left_join(df_2) %>% 
  group_by(element) %>%
  summarise(groups = toString(groups), sum = sum(values))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  element groups    sum
#    <int> <chr>   <int>
#1       1 A, B, C     6
#2       2 A, D        5
```

---

Or another option with `base R` would be to use a named key/value `vector` 'nm1') to change the values in the splitted `list` elements, `sum` and assign it to new column in 'df_1'

```
nm1 <- setNames(df_2$values, df_2$groups)
df_1$sum <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df_1$groups), ","), function(x) sum(nm1[x]))
```